# Determining hash of my own application as it is run?

Tags: c#

I want my C# Windows executable to determine its own HASH value. I know how to implement Hash, but how to determine at run-time?

Comment: What part are you asking about? What _exactly_ are you having problems with?

Comment: Is this an attempt at a security measure to try to prevent people from modifying the application?

Comment: You are not trying to re-invent code signing, are you ?

Comment: If any of the above are true, code-sign your application, and let .NET handle it :)

Comment: I want to secure my application from malwares.

Comment: Why would malware be interested in your program?  You need to have at least 100,000 installs before they start paying attention.  Are you close?

Comment: @RPK: Use code signing.  You're trying to re-implement a feature Microsoft correctly implemented a long time ago.  Besides that, this won't protect you from Malware, because the malware will simply patch out any checks you put in.  Just install to Program Files, and code-sign, and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if by hash you mean the public key token, or your own hashing algorithm.

With these you can simply get the public key token property from the assembly object:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // Assembly reference
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(); // Top level assembly reference
```

With this you can use your own hashing algorithm:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location // Filename
```

Comment: As I said in the comments to the original question, don't waste time trying to re-implement code signing.  .NET already does it as well or better than you're going to, and it doesn't protect you from malware anyhow, which (as you stated in the comment on the original question), was your goal.

Answer (score 3):

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` is the path to your executable. You can read it and compute it's hash with `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` or something.